# get the number of words in the string in java

Tags: java

This is the code I wrote for counting the words in a string.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class word1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("enter a line: ");
        String p =in.next();
        int q= p.length();
        int i;
        int count=0;
        for( i=0; i<q; i++)
        {
            if( p.charAt(i)==' ')
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(count);

    }
}
```

I have tried it a couple of times but **it is only giving me 0** as a result, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Have you checked that `p` actually contains what you think it does?

Answer (score 2):

Hi I agree you need to use nextLine()
But from what I understand counting ' ' (white space) is not a very good way to count word
It is better to use

```
String p = in.nextLine();
String[] list = p.split("\\W+"); 
System.out.print(list.length);
```

This way even if your string started with white space its still okay
This also enables you to skip multiple white space

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code produces `0` is that when you call

```
String p = in.next();
```

your string gets the first word, and then stops. `next()` scans up to the first delimiter, then returns.

Replace the call with

```
String p = in.nextLine();
```

to read the whole line.

Note that your approach is incorrect, because it relies on counting the number of spaces, not the number of words. This is not the same thing, because words can be separated with multiple spaces.

A better approach would be to call `next` repeatedly until `hasNext()` returns `false`, and print the number of times that you were able to call `next` successfully. This will be the number of words the user has entered.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `next()` with `nextLine()` otherwise it stops at the first word and doesn't continue.

---

### `Scanner#next()`

> **Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A
>   complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the
>   delimiter pattern.** This method may block while waiting for input to
>   scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.

---

### Scanner's default delimiters

> [...] A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter
>   pattern, which **by default matches whitespace**.[...]

---

### Solution

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("enter a line: ");
int count = (int)Pattern.compile("\\W+")
                        .splitAsStream(in.nextLine())
                        .count();
System.out.println(count);
```

Source : [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` by white-space and then get the size.

```
str = "Hello, a b c";
String[] splited = str.split("\\s+");
```

And also add another symbols to split by.